# Issues with parcelable array class in Android

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I have a class that I am trying to parce using parcelable to use with an adaptor.

These are the items (in brief)

```
public class Stops implements Parcelable{
    private String stop_id;
    private String type;
    private String location;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String from;
    private String to;

    private Commodities[] commodities;

.. etc etc etc
```

And the code to parce it:

```
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeArray(commodities);

}
private Stops(Parcel in){
    commodities = in.readArray(); // the error is right here
}
public static final Creator<Stops> CREATOR = new Creator<Stops>(){
    @Override
    public Stops createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Stops(source);
    }
    @Override
    public Stops[] newArray(int size){
        return new Stops[size];
    }
};
```

I am getting an error on

```
private Stops(Parcel in){
    commodities = in.readArray();
}
```

Some of the solutions involve changing `dest.writeArray()` to `dest.writeParcelable(etc etc`) although doing so
gives me a strange error saying that I am not passing a parcelable(commodities has its own class definition and it was made parcelable....which is why the error trips me out)

What would then be the best option to parce this?

The commodities class as requested:

```
public class Commodities  implements Parcelable{
    private String item;
    private String description;
    private String poNumber;
    private String qty;
    private String weight;

    public Commodities() {}

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPoNumber() {
        return poNumber;
    }

    public void setPoNumber(String poNumber) {
        this.poNumber = poNumber;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(item);
        dest.writeString(description);
        dest.writeString(poNumber);
        dest.writeString(qty);
        dest.writeString(weight);
    }
    private Commodities(Parcel in){
        item = in.readString();
        description  =in.readString();
        poNumber = in.readString();
        qty = in.readString();
        weight = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Commodities> CREATOR = new Creator<Commodities>() {
        @Override
        public Commodities createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Commodities(source);
        }
        @Override
        public Commodities[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Commodities[size];}
    };
}
```

And to give more context as to what I am trying to do. There are various stops(it is an array as well) which inside have an array of commodities. Both stops and commodities are populated accordingly. What I am trying to do is to send this information into a recyclerview adapter.

So each stop is an array with various data, part of that is another array of commodities.

Comment: Could you please share your `Commodities` class as well

Comment: @Gaurav absolutely, I have added it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need call `CREATER` for custom objects.

```
 public class Stops implements Parcelable {

    private String stop_id;
    private String type;
    private String location;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private Commodities[] commodities;


   protected Stops(Parcel in) {
    stop_id = in.readString();
    type = in.readString();
    location = in.readString();
    address = in.readString();
    city = in.readString();
    state = in.readString();
    zip = in.readString();
    from = in.readString();
    to = in.readString();
    commodities = in.createTypedArray(Commodities.CREATOR);
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(stop_id);
    dest.writeString(type);
    dest.writeString(location);
    dest.writeString(address);
    dest.writeString(city);
    dest.writeString(state);
    dest.writeString(zip);
    dest.writeString(from);
    dest.writeString(to);
    dest.writeTypedArray(commodities, flags);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<Stops> CREATOR = new Creator<Stops>() {
    @Override
    public Stops createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Stops(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Stops[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Stops[size];
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I thought so! Now my issue relies with being able to parse the whole thing in an adapter.Basically, how would you get this data to display stop and commodity data into a custom adapter? Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @sigillum_conf sorry but I'm didn't get your question. Please tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @sigillum_conf if you are trying to send data to adapter then simple pass the `Stops` array in constructor of adapter. But if `Stops` array is coming from some other screen to the screen containing `recyclerView` then first you need get parsed data like this : ` getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra("key")` and pass it to adapter constructor.-

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, I had to create a separate question for this since I could not resolve it, if you would like to give me a hand, the question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683912/recyclerview-adapter-of-array-pojo-class-with-inner-array-class

Comment: Hi @sigillum_conf sorry for late reply I saw your question and somone has given answer as well so no issues :)